# Can I use select2 in my website?

Tags: licensing, gpl, websites, apache

I am working on project that deals in customer support. This website actually sells products ( so it is commerical ), and provides customer support.  So in this project/website I was about to use [select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) .

Select2 License:

> This software is licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
>   "Apache License") or the GNU General Public License version 2 (the
>   "GPL License"). You may choose either license to govern your use of
>   this software only upon the condition that you accept all of the terms
>   of either the Apache License or the GPL License.

Can I use this in the website?
Ask me if any other info is also required.

Answer (score 4):

Apache license is a non-copyleft open-source license that does not require anything from you. You can use code covered by Apache version 2 license for anything you want.

The GPL *alternative* is there to permit combining the work with code covered by GPL version 2, because Apache version 2 license by itself is only compatible with GPL version 3.

Note that for *server side* you could even use GPL code in a website, because the requirements of GPL pertain to *distributing* the code and you are not distributing that code. You are distributing the JavaScript code though, so you need to rely on the Apache license option in this particular case.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure how the "not distributing" GPL exemption applies to client-side JavaScript.  You're technically distributing it to everyone who visits the web site.  Sencha, which develops Ext JS and distributes it under the GPL and a commercial license, would argue very strongly that you need a commercial license if you don't want to comply with the GPL requirements.

Comment: @JoshKelley: Ah, I didn't actually check whether the thing to be used is server-side or client-side; I'll reword it a bit.